# Graphics issue on ARM64 Ubuntu in UTM on M1 Pro?

Tags: 22.04, apple, arm64

In December I installed Ubuntu 22.04 in UTM on my M1 Pro MacBook Pro and everything was working fine. After I did an *apt-update* and *apt-upgrade* in January suddenly when opening the terminal or files manager, all that appeared was a blank, completely black window. They were still responsive, I could terminate them using "Quit" from the sidebar without any problem, so it looks like there was no crash or anything. So I tried to reinstall Ubuntu and now this issue already pops up when trying to install it. I am not able to do the installation because the installation wizard is not shown. It looks like this:

[ARM64 issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2FTf.png)

To me it looks like a graphics issue. My question is: Is there someone else who has the same issue? Does anyone have an idea why it no longer works? It worked fine until I did that update. Additionally, with 20.04.5 everything works perfectly fine, so what is the issue with 22.04.2?

Comment: What video card and driver are you using?

Comment: The Apple integrated GPU of the M1 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

Something with mesa updates...

https://github.com/utmapp/UTM/issues/4983

> Change the Emulated Display Card to virtio-ramfb or any other card without a -gl suffix.